# d3.js time scale axis ticks are not equally spaced

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have drawn my x axis using `d3.js-v3` time scale `d3.time.scale()`.
**My axis ticks are not equally spaced.**
[image]

How can I have equally spaced ticks?

Here is my code

```js
var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format("%d %b");

var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20
  },
  width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 20 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date("08/21/2019"), new Date("09/5/2019")])
  .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickFormat(customTimeFormat);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`d3.time.scale` creates one tick every two days, but resets the ticks on the 1st day of the Month, giving this unwanted impression that scale is not even.

This behaviour can be controlled by using [`ticks`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Scales.md#ticks) function as shown below.

`.ticks(d3.time.day, 1)` will display one tick per day.

```js
var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format("%d %b");

var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20
  },
  width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 20 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date("08/20/2019"), new Date("09/05/2019")])
  .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickFormat(customTimeFormat)
  .ticks(d3.time.day, 1);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ticks at 2 day interval by adding this to your axis definition

.ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(d => d3.timeDay.count(0, d) % 2 === 0))

see code snippet with d3 v5.7.0

```js
var customTimeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%d %b");

var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20
  },
  width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 20 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("08/20/2019"), new Date("09/7/2019")])
  .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom()
  .scale(x)
  .ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(d => d3.timeDay.count(0, d) % 2 === 0))
  .tickFormat(customTimeFormat);

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```